# Encode URL passed to JSTL list item

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jstl

In my tomcat web app, I implemented anti-csrf token like this:

```
<form method="post" action="<%=response.encodeURL("buy")%>">
```

So, the URL becomes: `http://10.0.0.129:8080/webapp/buy?CSRFToken=3B2D9F4ED12AB2237B690B8E3C4CD234`

However, when I have a `<c:forEach items="${forsales}" var="forsale">`:

```
<c:forEach items="${forsales}" var="forsale">
<tr>
<td align="center">${forsale.id}</td>
<td align="center"><a href="${forsale.commentUrl}">${forsale.name}</a></td>
<td align="center">${forsale.sellerid}</td>
<td align="center">${forsale.seller}</td>
<td align="center">${forsale.description}</td>
<td align="center"><fmt:formatNumber value="${forsale.price}" type="currency" /></td>
<td align="center">${forsale.stock}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

How to encode `<a href="${forsale.commentUrl}">`, for the link to include CSRFToken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the JSTL `<c:url>` instead of scriptlets.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<a href="<c:url value="${forsale.commentUrl}"/>">${forsale.name}</a>
```